# convert to right timezone trino

Tags: sql, presto, trino

I have an issue.

I don't find how to convert my column to the right timezone. example below :

```
SELECT 
     date AS date, --> how to convert to 'europe/paris' timezone 
FROM tableName
```

if you have an idea.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use `AT TIME ZONE`:

```sql
select now() at time zone 'Europe/Paris';
```

Output:

| _col0 |
| --- |
| 2022-11-11 12:00:59.405 Europe/Paris |